# rust enum with internal tuple and specific values

Tags: rust, enums

Is there any way to specify specific values to different enum variants and an internal tuple
to hold additional variables?
What I want is something like this:

```
#[repr(u8)]
enum Test {
a(String) = 0x01,
b(u32, u32) = 0x32,
c([u8;3]) = 0x44,
...
}
```

both of these are valid:

```
#[repr(u8)]
enum Test {
a(String),
b(u32, u32),
c([u8;3]),
...
}
#[repr(u8)]
enum Test1 {
a = 0x01,
b = 0x32,
c = 0x44,
...
}
```

If not, then what is the best way of achieving something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.21.1/strum_macros/derive.EnumDiscriminants.html or https://lib.rs/crates/enum-map-derive

Comment: Are the values known at compilation time (and immutable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is already implemented, and known as [`arbitrary_enum_discriminant`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2363-arbitrary-enum-discriminant.html), but [not yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/02b27f1e70fc60a8f2aa0982e80d7cde5889112e) released in a stable version.

You can wait until Rust 1.56.0 is released, which is [expected to be October 21st 2021](https://forge.rust-lang.org/), or use the unstable nightly build of compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`enum-map`](https://lib.rs/crates/enum-map), or you could just do something like this:

```
impl Test {
    #[inline]
    fn get_val(&self) -> u8 {
        match self {
            Self::a(_) => 0x01,
            Self::b(_, _) => 0x32,
            Self::c(_) => 0x44,
        }
    }
}
```